# Mutably use a value inside and outside of a closure

Tags: rust

Is there a way to mutably borrow (or move a reference to) some value into a closure and continue using it outside, in a cleaner way?

For example, I have this code:

```rust
let queue = Arc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));
let cqueue = Arc::clone(&queue);

EntityEventQueue::register_receiver(&entity_equeue, "position-callback",
    Box::new( move |e| {
        cqueue.borrow_mut().push(e.clone());
    }));

// mutate queue
```

It works, but I heard that `RefCell` is bad practice outside some specific uses. Is there a way that I can use `queue` both inside and outside of the closure?

And if there is not, do you know a better way of implementing this? The one requirement is that the queue must be outside of the `EntityEventQueue` structure

(I created the `register_receiver` method, so it can be altered. Its signature is `pub fn register_receiver(this: &Arc<RefCell<Self>>, name: &str, callback: Box<dyn FnMut(...) + 'a>`)

Comment: Why are you combining `Arc` and `RefCell`? Does your queue need to be thread safe, or not? `RefCell` is most commonly used in conjunction with `Rc`. Also, using `RefCell` is not bad practice if you need *single threaded interior mutability*.

Comment: Note that interior mutability will not allow aliasing mutability. You still can't have two `&mut` to a single `T`. That will panic (or block if using `Mutex`/`RwLock`). It just allows you to "hide" mutable borrows from the compiler, acting as if they're immutable borrows until you borrow mutably from the inner `RefCell`.

Comment: If all we given is this piece of code, we can't tell of a better way. Also, if all we given is this piece of code, this question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow (and maybe it isn't in general).

Answer (score 0):

You should use some synchronization mechanism instead of `RefCell`. For example a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or a [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html). Depending on your writing needs. Quick tip is:

- One writer (at a time) and several readers -> `RwLock`
- Many writers many readers -> `Mutex`

Those are `std` but you have some other synchronization libraries and mechanisms available.

Comment: I don't think this code is multi-threaded. It can't be since `RefCell` is `!Sync`, meaning the `Arc` is `!Send`, which means this [wouldn't compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84731e9388279eb053af13ea49ceb411) if the closure were being called on another thread. A multi-threaded callback would need a `+ Send + 'static` bound. Synchronization is unnecessary in a single-threaded program.